# C# Console.WriteLine from another Thead doesn't work

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

I have a simple problem that I can't resolve. I am learning how to use Thread in C#, and I try to write in the console from another Thread with that code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread thread = new Thread(myFunc);
    }

    public void myFunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
}
```

There is nothing printing on the output. If I move the WriteLine in the public MainWindow() it works... where is the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: A few tips: 1) do not use threads, use ThreadPool, TPL, Tasks. 2) do not test with the Console in a WinForms/WPF app.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the thread, but it is not running. You need to start the thread. Call `thread.Start()` after you create it.

Answer (score 1):

And even if you start the thread (as @mike mentioned and should be added) you will not see anything! Because before your thread get any chance to run your program (Main method) will end.

Comment: Actually I tried to start it and It works...

Comment: Well probably you are running it in debug mode. And it may print to console or may not; it depends on how the situation of OS core is, at the time, for scheduling threads. I did not went into details because I wanted to just provide something short and (hopefully) useful. And if you want to step into parallel programming in .NET, for now, skip using threads and learn TPL (Task Parallel Library) (IMHO and experience).

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
```

so the thread can start running and finish.